# Tableau: "Reference" column from parameter?

Tags: parameters, tableau-api

Cheers!

A quick question for the Tableau experts out there:  Is it possible to add in a "reference" column in a column chart that can be set with a parameter?

E.g., I have a bunch of columns (say values for each day) - I want one column at the end of the table that shows the value of a target set by parameter.

I can't figure out how to pull it off and haven't found any similar examples.  Is it possible?

Thanks!
J

Comment: Do you have an example workbook?

Answer (score 0):

You can place a parameter on any shelf just like any other field. Of course, if it is displayed multiple times, they will all show the same current value for the parameter.

If you are using measure names and measure values on your visualization, you may prefer to make a simple calculated field that is defined to be equal to the value of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex already said, Your solution is to create a calculate field that will return the value based upon the parameter.

For e.g.,

```
    IF [Select Date] = Date('01-06-2015') then
        [Value_For_Day_1]
    elseif [Select Date] = Date('02-06-2015') then
        [Value_For_Day_2]
    elseif [Select Date] = Date('03-06-2015') then
        [Value_For_Day_3]   
    end
```

Note that **i have compared exact dates, you may expand it to months, years etc and can even parameterize each component of the date being compared.**